# Query for all Buttons on all sObjects (where contentSource = OnClick JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, button, metadata, jsobject

Is there any way , In which - I can find out how many/details of all the Buttons in my org which use JavaScript in it.

**Edit :**

I want to find out all the Button which uses JavaScript as Content Source when we create a Button in SALESFORCE ORG/Acc  by going into

```
Setup - > Objects -> Button, Links & Actions – > Where Content Source = OnClick JavaScript
```

OR Lets make it more simple -

**How can I get List of all Button in sObject.**

**EDIT 2 :**

Till now I have got this - Is it useful to answer-

> SELECT id , Name, pageOrSobjectTYpe FROM WebLink where DisplayType=
>   'button'  and LinkType ='javascript';

( I dont understand why this question is not too informative/unclear after this much info given above - to do minus )

Comment: Check the code? A little bit more info please. Do you want to count all buttons on a running website? Do you want to check all the files in your project for buttons using your editor? Etc.

Comment: What might `org` be?

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: Shilly  & Sherali & @MinusFour : I want to find out all the Button which uses JavaScript in it through out SALESFORCE ORG/Acc. (Which are created in  Setup - > Objects -> Button, Links & Actions

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I believe the reason for the downvotes is that it doesn't specifically state you are searching Salesforce in the tags or in the title.  I found this question through a web search, and didn't realize it wasn't in the Salesforce StackExchange.  The questions folks are asking means they have no idea the platform you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone - This is what I was looking for -

```
SELECT id , Name, pageorsobjecttype, DisplayType, LinkType FROM WebLink 

WHERE DisplayType IN ('B','L') and LinkType ='javascript'
```